# How to use scikit-learn properly for text clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, tf-idf, text-processing

I always got error when using TfidfVectorizer for kmeans clustering.

There are 3 cases:

1. I use tokenizer parameter in TfidfVectorizer to customize tokenization process for my dataset. Here is my code:

`

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stops,tokenizer=tokenize)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(titles)
```

`

however i got this error :

```
ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words
```

2. I make a vocabulary consisting terms and document frequency for each term that was the result of the tokenization, so the code become like this:

`vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stops,tokenizer=tokenize,vocabulary=vocab)`

but i got another new error:

```
ValueError: Vocabulary contains repeated indices.
```

And lastly, i remove the tokenizer and vocabulary parameter. The code becomes like this:

`

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stops)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(titles)
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
true_k = 8
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)
print "Top terms per cluster:"
order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
for i in range(true_k):
    print "Cluster %d:" % i,
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        print ' %s' % terms[ind],
    print
```

`

Well, the program runs successfully but the clustering results are like this:

`

```
Cluster 0:  bangun,  rancang,  lunak,  perangkat,  aplikasi,  berbasis,  menggunakan,  service,  sistem,  pembangunan,
Cluster 1:  sistem,  aplikasi,  berbasis,  web,  menggunakan,  pembuatan,  mobile,  informasi,  teknologi,  pengembangan,
Cluster 2:  android,  berbasis,  aplikasi,  perangkat,  rancang,  bangun,  bergerak,  mobile,  sosial,  menggunakan,
Cluster 3:  implementasi,  algoritma,  menggunakan,  klasifikasi,  data,  game,  fuzzy,  vector,  support,  machine,
Cluster 4:  metode,  menggunakan,  video,  penerapan,  implementasi,  steganografi,  pengenalan,  berbasis,  file,  analisis,
Cluster 5:  citra,  segmentasi,  menggunakan,  implementasi,  metode,  warna,  tekstur,  kembali,  berwarna,  temu,
Cluster 6:  jaringan,  tiruan,  protokol,  voip,  syaraf,  saraf,  menggunakan,  implementasi,  kinerja,  streaming,
Cluster 7:  studi,  kasus,  its,  informatika,  teknik,  sistem,  informasi,  data,  surabaya,  jurusan,
```

`

Some terms are clustered into multiple clusters,like term `data` is placed to Cluster 3 and Cluster 7.

Can you tell me how to use the tfidfvectorizer and KMeans properly? Your help is my happiness :)

Comment: What are `titles`, 'vocab' ? `Can you tell me how to use the tfidfvectorizer and KMeans properly?` too vague as a question. You can write tons and tons of lines about it.

Comment: There's no problem with your results. A word can happen in different clusters with different probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the cluster of every term you can have:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stops)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(titles)
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
true_k = 8
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)

terms_vectorized = vectorizer.transform(terms)
terms_prediction = model.predict(terms_vectorized)
```

Then you'll get a prediction for every term which you can iterate over.

The results that you have show the importance of terms in every cluster not their prediction.

And the reason why you get those errors is because you can't have an input document with no term and somehow the arguments that you're passing to vectorizer is causing some documents to be like that.

Comment: can you tell me why the vectorizer passes empty vocabulary when i use parameter tokenizer for my own tokenizing function?
The terms in the clusters above wasn't stemmed at all so i had to use a function to stem them.
Many thanks :)

Comment: Even if for one of your documents your vectorizer doesn't find a term then it will throw that error. You can run your tokenizer alone over all the documents to find out which one doesn't have any terms (excluding stop terms). If you find that document, you'll know the problem. You can also solve the problem by adding a dummy term to all your documents so that none of them is empty (e.g. add the word 'dummy' to all your documents).